# useEffect doesn't set the current state from LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a app, that allows you to switch between two components, and I'm trying to save that in localstorage, and with useEffect set it, and useState change it whenever I want.

So the problem is that the local storage is currently switching the value and key correctly, and working fine, the only time doesn't work is when i reload the page even if the local storage says to use other component, it doesn't show, instead it shows the other component.

Here is the code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Absolutes from "./useables/Absolutes";
import ShowHadith from './routes/Hadiths';
import ShowQuran from './routes/Quran'

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  flex-direction: column;
`
const BntForChange = styled.button`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10%;
`

export default function App() {
  const [view, setView] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('view') === null ||
      localStorage.getItem('view') === undefined ||
      localStorage.getItem('view') === '') {
      setView('hadith');
      localStorage.setItem('view', 'hadith')
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('view', 'hadith')) {
      setView('hadith')
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('view', 'quran')) {
      setView('quran')
    }
  }, [])

  function change_view() {
    if (view === 'hadith') {
      setView('quran')
      localStorage.setItem('view', 'quran');
    } else {
      setView('hadith')
      localStorage.setItem('view', 'hadith');
    };
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Absolutes view={view} setview={setView} />
      {
        view === 'hadith' ? <ShowHadith /> : <ShowQuran />
      }
      <BntForChange onClick={() => change_view()}>Change View</BntForChange>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it using `localStorage.getItem('view') === 'currentState'`, instead of using `localStorage.getItem('view', 'currentState')`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
else if (localStorage.getItem('view', 'hadith')) {
  setView('hadith')
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('view', 'quran')) {
  setView('quran')
}
```

with this,

```
else if (localStorage.getItem('view') === 'hadith') {
  setView('hadith')
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('view') === 'quran') {
  setView('quran')
}
```

or replace the same with this,

```
else{
  setView(localStorage.getItem('view'))
}
```